# No sound after compiling Realtek driver on Mint

Tags: drivers, audio, alsa

I messed up big time. I wanted to update my drivers, so I downloaded drivers from Realtek's site for unix/linux. I unpacked it, then used `make`, but there was an error (something related to DATE) so I decided not to do it. Sadly after restarting my laptop, I don't have sound. How can I throw everything related to my 'new driver' away and resume using my old driver (or install it again)?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a `make uninstall`. (Well, given the success so far, do you feel lucky?)

The sounds driver modules are part of the kernel package; the user-space libraries and some configuration are in the `alsa-lib` package. Reinstall them.